# "Life decreed better!" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check, sentence-translation, translation-explanation

Sort of, related to [my another qestion](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/is-heaven-decreed-better-a-correct-translation-for-di-melius).

I am looking for mo secular (for the lack of a better word) version of a phrase "*Di melius!*".
While I know that [*deus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deus#Latin) could be interpreted as "*destiny*" or "*heaven*".

I'd like something like "*Life decreed better!*" (by "life" meaning it simply happened this way) or "*Destiny decreed better!*" (but without supernatural connotation of *deus*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply replace *di* (the gods) by *vita* (life) or *fatum* (fate), or its plural *fata*.

Comment: With the caveat that *fatum* does also have a supernatural connotation, but I don't think it's possible to talk about destiny without that anyway.